# Issue building substrate on linux

Tags: testing

I'm trying to run the substrate tests with `cargo test --workspace` but seeing the following errors on linux (it works on a mac):

```
error: proc macro panicked
    --> substrate/frame/support/src/lib.rs:2623:10
     |
2623 |     #[doc = docify::embed!("src/lib.rs", example_storage_value_append)]
     |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = help: message: internal error: entered unreachable code

error: proc macro panicked
    --> substrate/frame/support/src/lib.rs:2629:10
     |
2629 |     #[doc = docify::embed!("src/lib.rs", example_storage_value_try_append)]
     |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = help: message: internal error: entered unreachable code

   Compiling sc-basic-authorship v0.34.0 (/home/../polkadot-sdk/substrate/client/basic-authorship)
error: proc macro panicked
    --> substrate/frame/support/src/lib.rs:2638:10
     |
2638 |     #[doc = docify::embed!("src/lib.rs", example_storage_value_decode_len)]
     |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = help: message: internal error: entered unreachable code

   Compiling mmr-rpc v28.0.0 (/home/../polkadot-sdk/substrate/client/merkle-mountain-range/rpc)
error: proc macro panicked
    --> substrate/frame/support/src/lib.rs:2686:10
     |
2686 |     #[doc = docify::embed!("src/lib.rs", example_storage_value_map_prefixes)]
     |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = help: message: internal error: entered unreachable code
```

I've tried cloning [docify repo](https://github.com/sam0x17/docify) and running `cargo test`:

```
> cargo test
   Compiling docify v0.2.7 (/home/../docify)
error: proc macro panicked
  --> examples/integration.rs:92:9
   |
92 | #[doc = docify::embed!("examples/samples.rs", inner_mod2)]
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: message: internal error: entered unreachable code
error: could not compile `docify` (example "integration") due to previous error
> rustc --version
rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)
```

Any tips on how to resolve it would be appreciated

Comment: What linux are you using? Any WSL? And what version of the repo is it? Just tested on Ubuntu 23.10 and it works both.

Comment: Maybe WSL is the issue, I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL. Thanks for confirming, will check my local env

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi thanks that was it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was an issue with my local setup. Everything working as it should on WSL Ubuntu 22.04 and rustc 1.75

Comment: Not sure what the issue with 20.04 was, but it has already reached its EOL. But it might be better to add handling for the panic using `runtime/debug`